# How to properly configure Domain Delegation to send email through one domain with a FROM address of another domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server

We're having some email deliverability problems and I've tracked it down to a couple of issues:

1. SPF/DKIM records are mismatched
2. Our app is sending mail from one domain on behalf of another without permission

Our app is set up to send mail through a mail server at *companymailserver.com*, but we're changing the FROM address to come from *support@companyname.com*.

I can't quite figure out what needs to be done to authorize *companymailserver.com* to send mail on behalf of *support@companyname.com*

I know I need to handle this with Domain Delegation, but I'm at a loss on how to actually set that up.

If someone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

To authorize *companymailserver.com* to send mail for *companyname.com* you would need to add an SPF record to the *companyname.com* public DNS to specify that it is allowed.

`companyname.com IN TXT v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ip4:2.3.4.5 -all`